# 3 jugs - problem conceptulising a solution

Tags: python

So the jug problem is quite famous. Using 2 jugs of capacity a and b, yield volume d. The jugs have no markings.

So I wanted to try solve it for 3 jugs of capacity a, b and c.

The code below shows a solution for a single problem where jugs are size:
5, 3, and 1 and the target volume is 4. I have listed all the possible combinations for the programme to work through as possibleStates just because it makes it easier to explain the issue I am having.

So my code basically just empties the largest jug into the second largest jug if there is space and so on (it works upwards first for smaller jugs, e.g: if 5 is empty and 3 is full, 3 will go into 5). Obviously though (as demonstrated for solution Solution for: (5, 0, 0)) this isn't always the best way. With (5,0,0) the best way is actually to empty 5 into 1. That would be 2 steps to get 4: (5,0,0) and (4,0,1).

The only reason (5,3,0) yields the correct answer is because 5 cannot empty into jug 2 so empties as much as possible into jug 1.

My question is, how do I code the three jug problem to ensure I can find the solution (5,0,0) in one further step (4,0,1) rather than iterating through (2,3,0).....?

**The truth is, I am actually interested in coding a solution for any number of jugs, but cannot conceptually work out how to do this**

Please note I am a beginner programmer and don't know much about functions beyond loops.

```
global memory
global listSolution

capacity = (5,3,1)
#Set jug capacity 
jug1Max = capacity[0]
jug2Max = capacity[1]
jug3Max = capacity[2]

def statusJugs(state):
  #set jug status 
  jug1 = state[0]
  jug2 = state[1]
  jug3 = state[2]

  if(jug1==4 or jug2==4 or jug3 ==4):
      listSolution.append(state)
      return True

  #Has jug state been visited 
  if((jug1,jug2,jug3) in memory):
      return False

  memory[(jug1,jug2,jug3)] = 1

  #empty jug1
  if(jug1>0):
      #empty jug1 into jug2
      if(jug1+jug2<=jug2Max):
          if(statusJugs((0,jug1+jug2,jug3))):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True
      else:
          if(statusJugs((jug1-(jug2Max-jug2), jug2Max, jug3)) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True
      #empty jug1 into jug3
      if(jug1+jug3<=jug3Max):
          if( statusJugs((0,jug2,jug1+jug3))):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True
      else:
          if( statusJugs((jug1-(jug3Max-jug3), jug2, jug3Max)) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True

  #empty jug2
  if(jug2>0):
      #empty jug2 into jug1
      if(jug1+jug2<=jug1Max):
          if( statusJugs((jug1+jug2, 0, jug3)) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True
      else:
          if( statusJugs((jug1Max, jug2-(jug1Max-jug1), jug3)) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True
      #empty jug2 into jug3
      if(jug2+jug3<=jug3Max):
          if( statusJugs((jug1, 0, jug2+jug3)) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True
      else:
          if( statusJugs((jug1, jug2-(jug3Max-jug3), jug3Max)) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True

  #empty jug3
  if(jug3>0):
      #empty jug3 into jug1
      if(jug1+jug3<=jug1Max):
          if( statusJugs((jug1+jug3, jug2, 0)) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True
      else:
          if( statusJugs((jug1Max, jug2, jug3-(jug1Max-jug1))) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True
      #empty jug3 into jug2
      if(jug2+jug3<=jug2Max):
          if( statusJugs((jug1, jug2+jug3, 0)) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True
      else:
          if( statusJugs((jug1, jug2Max, jug3-(jug2Max-jug2))) ):
              listSolution.append(state)
              return True

  return False

possibleStates = [(5,3,1),(5,3,0),(5,0,1),(5,0,0),(0,3,1),(0,3,0),(0,0,1)]
for counter in range (0,len(possibleStates)):
    listSolution = []
    memory={}
    initial_state = possibleStates[counter]
    print("Solution for:",possibleStates[counter])
    statusJugs(initial_state)
    listSolution.reverse()
    print (listSolution)
    print ("Length of solution is:", len(listSolution))
    print ("\n=======End of solution=======")
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a really good exercise in Object-Oriented Programming.  I suggest you take some time to learn about that (with Python).  Done right you would end up with much simpler code that is a lot easier to check and understand.  Good luck!